# How to remove Unity from Ubuntu?

Tags: unity

I recently installed Ubuntu unity flavor using a partition.
I now want to remove the partition and give all the space back to regular Ubuntu. I am fine if Unity is completely erased. I do not have any files stored on the partition. Is there any command that will help me to remove Unity, without damaging regular Ubuntu?